# How can I force my app to launch with different language

Tags: ios, localization, build-time

I localized my app in multiple languages, and I want to force it to launch with a specific language. I've tried setting my language in user defaults for "AppleLanguages" key, it worked, but in the first launch, the language is still English. I need to change the language at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Changing AppleLanguages works only when you restart the app to do this without closing the app change the bundle to the name of the needed language so that NSLocalizedString reads from it instead of main bundle.